# Javascript best way to handle binded element events in ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery ui automplete widget bind:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.zip-code-input').autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            // Get list of zip codes 
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            // Do something with the selected item
        }
    });
});
```

Works fine for all zip code elements which are loaded on page request. Now i have to load a html form via ajax with a zip code input in it. Of course the autocomplete doesn't work. How can i handle it, without copy and past the same javascript code into the ajax loaded content?

Comment: Put this into a named function, so you can call it on the new element after you load it with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function addAutoComplete(inputIdentifier){
   $(inputIdentifier).autocomplete({
     minLength: 2,
     source: function (request, response) {
        // Get list of zip codes 
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // Do something with the selected item
    }
 });
```

Then after your HTML loads,

```
addAutoComplete(INPUT_IDENTIFIER);
```